# !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file fmex8.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading

Tags: errors

I got a strange anomaly today.

Basic information

- system: macOS Monterey
- distribution: TeX Live 2022
- compilation tool: `pdflatex`

Several days ago, I installed the mtpro2 package. And I put the file `fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map` provided by the package into `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

aaa\footnote{$\sum$}

\end{document}
```

This produces the error as said in the post title.

If not using the `amsmath` package, i.e.,

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

aaa\footnote{$\sum$}

\end{document}
```

No error occurs.

After deleting the `pdftex.map` from the local texmf tree, everything goes well in both cases.

So what's the problem?

Comment: please don't use external links, make a small self contained file that shows the problem and add as a code block

Comment: I have no fmex font in texlive, but also your main.tex has no commands to change the font from the default cm fonts?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have installed the mtpro2 font several days ago, does this font package has something to do with the error?

Comment: as I say, make a document that shows the error and has no unneeded packages, and add here so someone can trace

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have updated my post.

Comment: you shouldn't normally edit the map file by hand but presumably your edit broke it but as you haven't shown the code can't say what is wrong

Comment: map files should normally be managed via `updmap-sys`

Comment: texlive has pdftex.map in `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map`  which starts`% Don't change this file directly. Use updmap[-sys] instead.` if I understand your description you have masked this map file with an incomplete one earlier the path

Comment: So there is need to put the `pdftex.map` into the local texmf tree?@DavidCarlisle

Comment: I have not touched a pdftex.map for some decades so hard to guess what you did. https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/mtpro2 doesn't have a pdftex.map for example

Comment: does your local pdftex.map contains a line with the string `fmex`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, it does.

Comment: show the complete line.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/armeyer/mcs_web/blob/617db339647137f020ec27784fc293fc53339532/macros/mtp2fonts/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map#L477-L479)@UlrikeFischer

Comment: texlive2007 sounds a bit old. I can find a few traces of these fonts on the net, but everything is very old. I would suspect that you have old local files around and they now found their way into your pdftex.map. Run `updmap-sys --listmaps`, check that it updates your pdftex.map and then check the maps it uses for clues where your entries are from. If `updmap-sys` doesn't update this map, then better remove it and use `updmap-sys` to enable the entries for mtpro2.